# Can someone explain to me how the for-in loop is called 3 times here?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

Here's the code:

```
var InvertedPeninsula = function() {
  this.inhabitants = [
    {
      name: 'Sir Charles',
      race: 'Human'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ealei',
      race: 'Elf'
    }
  ];
  // Adds an extra humans method property to the inhabitants array to return all Humans
  this.inhabitants.humans = function() { /* returns all Human inhabitants */ };
};

// Create a new invertedPeninsula
var invertedPeninsula = new InvertedPeninsula();

// Log the name of each invertedPeninsula inhabitant
for (var i in invertedPeninsula.inhabitants) {
  console.log(invertedPeninsula.inhabitants[i].name);
}
```

To me, it looks like it's called 2x. Where does the 3x come from? There are only 2 cells in the array.

Comment: If you examine the value of `i`, all will become clear.

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) (not sure whether duplicate)

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly the pitfall one comes across when they use `for...in` to iterate an array.
A `for...in` iterates through all the *enumerable properties*, and hence `humans` is being iterated too.

There are of course 2 objects in the array but for sure has three *properties*: `0`, `1`, `humans` and hence 3 times.

```
invertedPeninsula.inhabitants.forEach(function(habitat){
   console.log(habitat.name);
});
```

`Array.forEach` is your best bet as it iterates over numbered properties. A normal `for` loop would also do.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has the following values: `0, 1, 'humans'` infact you added the element with the name 'humans' with the following code:

```
this.inhabitants.humans = function() { /* returns all Human inhabitants */ };
```

To check it try this code:

```
var InvertedPeninsula = function() {
  this.inhabitants = [
    {
      name: 'Sir Charles',
      race: 'Human'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ealei',
      race: 'Elf'
    }
  ];
  // Adds an extra humans method property to the inhabitants array to return all Humans
  this.inhabitants.humans = function() { /* returns all Human inhabitants */ };
};

// Create a new invertedPeninsula
var invertedPeninsula = new InvertedPeninsula();

// Log the name of each invertedPeninsula inhabitant
for (var i in invertedPeninsula.inhabitants) {
  console.log(i);   // CHANGED LINE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for...in` iterates all (inherited and own) enumerable properties.

When you create a  property using an assignment, it is defined as enumerable. You can make it non-enumerable (and thus not iterated by `for...in`) using

```js
Object.defineProperty(this.inhabitants, 'humans', {enumerable: false});
```

```js
var InvertedPeninsula = function() {
  this.inhabitants = [
    {
      name: 'Sir Charles',
      race: 'Human'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ealei',
      race: 'Elf'
    }
  ];
  // Adds an extra humans method property to the inhabitants array to return all Humans
  this.inhabitants.humans = function() { /* returns all Human inhabitants */ };
  Object.defineProperty(this.inhabitants, 'humans', {enumerable: false});
};

// Create a new invertedPeninsula
var invertedPeninsula = new InvertedPeninsula();

// Log the name of each invertedPeninsula inhabitant
for (var i in invertedPeninsula.inhabitants) {
  console.log(invertedPeninsula.inhabitants[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Rather: If you want to iterate the inhabitants, use the proper loop.

Comment: @Bergi Right, I didn't see it was an array.